# Why does smart contract successfully deploying to Rinkeby fail to deploy to mainnet?

Tags: solidity, truffle, gas, gas-price, truffle-deployment

`truffle.js`:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
var mnemonic = "";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
      rinkeby: {
      provider: function() { 
       return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/");
      },
      network_id: 4,
      gasPrice: "450000000", 
    },
    live: {
      networkCheckTimeout: 100000, 
      provider: function() { 
       return new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/");
      },
      network_id: 1,
      gasPrice: "450000000",

    },
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.8.4",

    },
  },
};
```

Successfully deploying to Rinkeby:

```
   > transaction hash:    
   > Blocks: 1            Seconds: 17
   > contract address:    
   > block number:        8751194
   > block timestamp:     1623504143
   > account:             
   > balance:             18.7469330662
   > gas used:            1476936 (0x168948)
   > gas price:           0.45 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.0006646212 ETH

   > Saving artifacts
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:        0.0006646212 ETH


Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   1
> Final cost:          0.0006646212 ETH
```

Error while deploying to mainnet:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"ContractName" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
   * Account:  
   * Balance:  991972954849359 wei
   * Message:  insufficient funds for gas * price + value
   * Try:
      + Using an adequately funded account
      + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:365:1
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at Migration._deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:74:1)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:61:1)
    at Migration.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:212:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:87:1)
    at runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:263:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:226:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:136:1)
Truffle v5.2.4 (core: 5.2.4)
Node v14.15.0
```

My balance is clearly more than that required by the transaction. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-calculate the amount of ETH you need for the mainnet deployment as follows:

```
deploymentCostInETH = gasAmount * gasPrice
```

`deploymentCostInETH` differs depending on the current gas price.

`gasAmount` is going to be the same for mainnet as it was for the testnet or any other network you deploy that specific contract to, which is 1476936. `gasAmount` depends on the contract's compiled bytecode.

`gasPrice` is what makes `deploymentCostInETH` differ across networks or over time, since it depends on the current gas price which depends on factors like network congestion.

Assuming today's average mainnet gas price (13 gwei = 13 * 10^9 wei = 13 * 10^-9 ETH), the calculation result would be:

```
deploymentCostInETH = 1476936 * 13 * 10^-9 = 0.019200168 ETH
```